# taskhost.exe uses a lot of CPU and does not quit

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage

The executable `taskhost.exe` is running twice and one process takes more than 50% of CPU. It increases the fan noise and slows the computer down. When i end the process with task manager the computer runs normal but the `takshost.exe` starts again after sometime slowing down the computer.

I thought it would do some unfinished job so i let it run for the whole night when I slept, but it continued the entire time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taskhost is used to run processes that are run from DLL files rather than from their own executable, so the real culprit could be anywhere on your system.  To start with I would recommend full system virus and malware scans.

There is a similar question on the [Microsoft answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/the-taskhostexe-application-consumes-50-60-of-the/0882ab46-43ee-4d90-8404-6802f8f4f2cf) site that lends some further insight.

Answer (score 1):

> berniemansell   03-25-2010 at 02:53:22 AM
>
> .
>
>
>
>  Anyway - my cpu was being consumed by the Windows Reliability Analysis Task - the way that I narrowed it down to this was by installing process explorer and letting it show me what was actually running under taskhost.exe
>
> I then went into scheduled tasks and stopped the reliability analysis scheduled activity - and presto the taskhost.exe went away and processor utilization shot down to essentially nothing.
>
> Anyway - that seemed to help me... maybe it will help you
>
> Not sure why it is trying to burn up so much cpu...

[From here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/5032-63-taskhost-running)

Comment: i have process explorer but even in that it shows the same.. and there is no process is under taskhost.exe

Comment: From reading the linked forum - and BBlake's comment above, taskhost.exe is unlikely to be the culprit. Something else is loading DLL's into memory and they display as taskhost.exe within task manager. The same way that svchost.exe is used.